# NVD3 redraw chart on load 'show'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to redraw the NVD3 chart on `load` or `show`.. but it doesn't work because I need that for my page that I need to be chart `display:none;` but the chart is after reload `width;25px;` but I set up to be `100%` of window width..

Everything works fine when I resizing the browser just it wont work when i load the page... I wrote this code for that:

```js
 // SLIDEUP
  $('#slide').click(function(){
    $('#border2').slideToggle(500);
    $('#slide1').slideToggle(500);
  });

  $('#slide').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#slide1').tab('show')
    $('#chart1 svg').trigger('resize'); // Added this line to force NVD3 to redraw the chart
});
```

```css
   /* CHART */
   #slide1 {display: none; position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; right: 25px;}
   #chart1 { width: 100%; height: 25em; }
```

```html
<div id="slide1">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="margin-chart">
        <svg id="chart1"></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

Thats is not a really clear version but works really well, i hop that i help someone..

I just did that by `.animation` that i set height 0 so the chart can be fully loaded and then via jQuery i set the `.animation` for height expand and its works perfectly.. Here is the code vo NVD3 or other chart ( tested with NVD3 and Rickshawn charts )

```js
  $('#slide').click(function(){
    $('#border2').slideToggle(500);
  });

  $("#slide").click(function(){
    if($('.slide1').hasClass('showtable')) {
        $('.slide1.showtable').animate({height:300},500).removeClass('showtable');
  } else { 
        $('.slide1').animate({height:0},500)
        $('.slide1').addClass('showtable');
      }
  });
```

```css
   /* CHART */
   .slide1 { position: relative; width: 100%; right: 25px;}
   .slide1.showtable {height: 0;}
    #chart1 {height: 300px;}
```

```html
<div class="slide1 showtable">
     <svg id="chart1"></svg>
</div>
```